# What does the second "it" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

A friend sent me this a few days ago and I have trouble understanding this sentence. What does the second "it" refer to in this sentence?

> It's only once we have reduced reason to one input among many in our decision procedures that we can begin the process of eliminating it.

Comment: The first **It's** or the second **it**?

Comment: the second "it".

Comment: Don't feel too bad about not being able to parse this sentence.  It's poorly constructed :)  I've tried to construct a better version for you, but it's unclear what the sentence is even trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second **it**, then, refers to **reason**. It's a little tricky to parse since there's a lot of waffle in the latter part of the sentence, but we could shorten it thus:

> It's only once we have reduced **reason** to one input [...] that we can [...] eliminate **it**.

The sentence is saying that you need to devalue the idea of **reason**, and turn it into just one thing to be considered among lots of others, before you can stop considering **reason** at all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it refers to "reason" if your sentence is rewritten like this:

"Once we have reduced reason to one input among many (inputs) in our decision procedures, we can begin the process of eliminating it."